# Can you boot NTFS Flash Drive?

Tags: boot, ntfs, bootable-media

I want to make an bootable Hirens DVD (And a Windows 7) but everytime I tried it on a NTFS drive. It failed.

Is there a way? Is it really impossible to boot from NTFS?

Comment: Hiren's is bootable but in  optical media, at least, where the file system is certainly not NTFS. The same for the  Windows 7 installer. For UEFI mode the Win7 installer must be in a USB stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a lot about configuring bootloaders, I highly recommend using grub4dos, and building your own boot menu and chainloading the ntldr... if not, try using a tool like the "[Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)" which can install hirens on a thumb-drive, and supports NTFS.